# Why do some custom made characters show up as "Creation 1" to other people online?

Tags: soul-calibur-5

I've been told that one of my characters shows up as "Creation1" in online matches. I've seen it happen to other people as well.

It seems to happen mostly on characters themed after someone specific. Mine is "Conan", so I'm wondering if there is a name ban list or something. Do some IP related names get automatically converted to "Creation 1"? Does anyone know if there's a full list somewhere?  I haven't been able to find any info on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen this myself and there are a couple of issues:

- **Connection Problems** - The attempt to download the name and model failed
- **Reported as Offensive** - Your name or avatar was deemed offensive and censored.
- **Muted** - Someone muted you, rendering their avatar the default. This also happens when they mute everyone.
- **Blacklisted** - As you suggested a name can be blacklisted, although I don't think it is tied to intellectual property as much as user submitted reports.

Comment: Interesting. I'll have to try out some others. I have a strong suspicion it won't let me do "Rambo" or "Batman" either.

Comment: Seems that profanity is automatically censored.